# Solve the differential equation $y'+4xy=4x\sqrt{y}$ and also find the maximal interval of the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $y'+4xy=4x\sqrt{y}$ and also find the
> maximal interval of the solution.

**My attempt:-**
Given differential equation is a Bernoulli's equation. I could solve using the [method](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/ch2/bernoulli.html#:%7E:text=A%20Bernoulli%20differential%20equation%20is,equations%20have%20no%20singular%20solutions.).

I got the solution $y(x)=(ce^{-x^2}+1)^2$.

I understood the case where $C\ge 0.$ When $C\ge0$. Then the maximal domain of the $y(x)$ is  $I=\mathbb R$.

> What happen when $c<0?$

$y(x)$ is defined for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Right?

But in the textbook, it is given that $I=(\sqrt{\ln(-c)},\infty).$ How did they get maximal interval like this for the solution?

Also, How did they split the cases as $c\ge0$ and $c<0$

Comment: It seems to be that in order to fulfill the dif. eq. we need to be able to evaluate 

$$\sqrt y=\sqrt{(ce^{-x^2}+1)^2}=|ce^{-x^2}+1|$$

but then we don't need that $\;ce^{-x^2}+1>0\;$ , which is what is required in order to get the domain $\;(\sqrt{\log(-c)}, \infty)\;$ . Either we're missing something or this is a mistake in that textbook.

Answer (score 1):

When we substitute your solution in the LHS of the ODE, we obtain
$$
4x(ce^{-x^2}+1), \tag{1}
$$
whereas in the RHS we obtain
$$
4x|ce^{-x^2}+1|. \tag{2}
$$
These expressions are equal iff $ce^{-x^2}+1\geq 0$. If $c<0$, this condition implies $|x|\geq\sqrt{\ln(-c)}$.

Comment: Could you tell me the procedure of finding the maximal domain?

Comment: Ah, this is what we were missing!. Nice. +1

Comment: I got LHS = $y'+4xy=2(ce^{-x^2}+1)(ce^{-x^2}(-2x))+4x(ce^{-x^2}+1)^2.$

Comment: $=(ce^{-x^2}+1)(-4cxe^{-x^2}+4cxe^{-x^2}+4x)=4x(ce^{-x^2}+1).$

Comment: Thank you. I have one more doubt. How does $c<0 \implies |x|\ge \sqrt{\ln(-c)}.$

Comment: $ce^{-x^2}+1\ge 0\implies 1\ge (-c)e^{-x^2}\implies ln(1)\ge \ln(-c)+(-|x|^2)(\because  ln(x)$ is an increasing function.)

Comment: Hence we get. $|x|\ge \sqrt{\ln(-c)}$.

Comment: Still in doubt?

Comment: yeah. Is it the general method for finding the maximal interval? How do I case for different values of $c$?

Comment: Consider $2y(x−1)y′ +y^2 = 4x(3x−2)$, I got the general solution as $y(x)=\pm \sqrt{4x^2+\frac{c}{x-1}}$

Comment: I got $\sqrt{y(x)}=ce^{-x^2}+1$. Then I squared. I don't understand. How did you take modulus.

Comment: Is there any assumption that $\sqrt{y(x)}\ge 0$. I mean. Is it the positive root?

Comment: Yes, by convention $\sqrt{(\cdot)}$ denotes the positive branch of the square root.