# Solve the differential equation $y'-2y=e^{2x}. $ Find the maximal interval of the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Still I don't understand this concept of finding maximal interval of the solution.

Consider the differential equation $y'-2y=e^{2x}. $ Find the maximal interval of the solution.

My attempt:

I got the general solution as $y(x)=(c+x)e^{2x}$.

How do I find the maximal interval of the solution?

I followed the steps in the answer given in the question.
[Solve the differential equation $y'+4xy=4x\sqrt{y}$ and also find the maximal interval of the solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814895/solve-the-differential-equation-y4xy-4x-sqrty-and-also-find-the-maximal-in)

I substituted the general solution in the differential equation.
I got $LHS=(x+c).2.e^{2x}+e^{2x}-2(x+c)e^{2x}$
$RHS=e^{2x}$
Comparing LHS and RHS. We get $(x+c)=1$

I really don't know how do I proceed further. Answer given in the textbook is $I=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hint: First of all, to clarify, the interval definition depends, in general, by the initial condition $y(0)=y_0$...that is, by $c$, in your case. 
Then, the differential equation you provided has strong continuity properties (globally Lipschitz in y fixed x, continuous in x), and probably it satisfies the condition for global existence of your textbook/notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtained a solution ( a family of solutions, really) of the differential equation, which is defined for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, the maximal interval of definition is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But why did he substitute the family of solution in the ode and obtained the condition in the following question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814895/solve-the-differential-equation-y4xy-4x-sqrty-and-also-find-the-maximal-in

Comment: Could you tell me the general method for finding the maximal interval of the solution?

Comment: Consider $2y(x−1)y'+y^2=4x(3x−2)$
, I got the general solution as $y(x)^2=4x^2+\frac{c}{x-1}$.

Comment: There is no general method. The Picard-Lindelof theorem guarantees, under certain conditions, that an initial value problem has one and only one solution in a neighborhood of the initial condition. It also provides specific bounds for this neighborhood. Then, you know that if you are able to extend this interval, the solutions coincide in the smaller interval.

Comment: In your example, you must provide the initial condition, without the initial condition you cannot define the maximal interval of definition.

Comment: In the textbook, they have found the maximal interval by casing the value of $c$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815228/solve-the-differential-equation-y-2y-e2x-find-the-maximal-interval-of-th/4815236#4815236

Comment: The value of $c$ is established from the initial condition. Casing on $c$ is the same as casing on the initial condition.

Comment: Could you tell me how do I case  $y(x)^2=4x^2+c/(x-1)$? Should I ask it as differnt question?

Comment: What are the cases arises for each such family of solutions?

Comment: Is it necessarily have the cases $c<0, c=0 and c<0$?

Comment: This solution blows up for $c\not=0$ at $x=1\,.$ The initial condition is  $y(0)=-c\,.$ Now draw a picture to find the maximal intervals the solutions exist in.

Comment: It is given that $y(1)=2$, $y=2|x|$ has the interval $I=(-\infty, 0)\cup (0,\infty)$. Why did they discard $x=0$?

Comment: @KurtG.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815599/find-the-solution-of-2yx%e2%88%921y-y2-4x3x%e2%88%922-with-initial-condition-y1-2