# Find the solution of $2y(x−1)y′ +y^2 = 4x(3x−2)$ with initial condition $y(1)=2$ and hence find the maximal interval interval of the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution  of $2y(x−1)y′ +y^2 = 4x(3x−2)$ with initial condition $y(1)=2$ and hence find the maximal interval interval of the solution.

My attempt:-
We get the solution of the differential equation as $y^2=4x^2+\frac{c}{x-1}\implies y=\pm\sqrt{4x^2+\frac{c}{x-1}}$.
In order to satisfy the initial condition $c=0.$ and thus $y=2|x|$. But the maximal interval of definition of the solution given is $\mathbb R$. Right? But $y'(0)$ is not defined.So, this is not the actual solution. I don't understand how to find the maximal interval of the solution. Could you help me?
I tried different examples. still I don't understand how to find the maximal interval.
[Solve the differential equation $y'-2y=e^{2x}. $ Find the maximal interval of the solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815228/solve-the-differential-equation-y-2y-e2x-find-the-maximal-interval-of-th/4815236?noredirect=1#comment10246012_4815236)

Comment: $y=2x$ is a solution to the ODE satisfying $y(1)=2$.

Comment: How did you get like that?

Comment: You can write the solution to $y^2= 4x^2$ as $y=\pm 2|x|$, but also as $y=\pm 2x$.

Comment: @Unknownx It is basic courtesy in this site to accept and upvote helpful answers. It is the only way you reward the person who took time to write up and answer to help you with your query. You have not done so in most of your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the ODE can be written as $(y^2)'(x-1) + y^2 = 4x(3x-2)$. So we define $z(x):=y(x)^2$, and it becomes a linear, inhomogeneous ODE in $z$: $z'(x-1) + z = 4x(3x-2)$, denoted by $(*)$. This can be solved with standard methods.

**1. Solving the ODE**.
First, the solution to the homogeneous equation $z'(x-1) + z = 0$ is $z_h=\frac{C}{x-1}$. The solution to the inhomogeneous equation $(*)$ is found by replacing $C$ with an unknown function $C(x)$, i.e. making the ansatz $z(x) = \frac{C(x)}{x-1}$, and plugging this in $(*)$ in order to find $C(x)$. This yields $C(x) = 4x^2(x-1) + D$, where $D$ is the remaining integration constant. Thus, the general solution is $$z(x)=\frac D{x-1} + 4x^2.\qquad (**)$$

Solving the initial value problem, need to incorporate $z(1) = 4$ (follows from $y(1)=2$). Note that $z(1)$ is not defined iff $D\neq 0$, thus we require $D=0$, and we indeed find in this case that $z(1)=4$. Note that any other initial condition $z(1)\neq 4$ would not yield a solution, as can be seen by taking the limit $x\to 1$ in $(**)$.

Finally, going back to $y$: We take the square root, and pick the positive branch (note that $y(1)=-2$ would also be admissible given $z(1)=4$), which gives $y(x) = +\sqrt{4x^2} = 2x$.

**2. Interval** of the solution: The case $D=0$ is special, in that $y(x) = 2x$ satisfies the ODE on all of $\mathbb R$, and *$y'(1)$ is defined for that solution*. Once you know that this is your solution, it is a simple matter of plugging it in the ODE, to see that this is a solution on all $x\in\mathbb R$.

- For any other initial condition $y(1) \notin\{-2, 2\}$ the ODE will not have a solution at all.
- For all other initial conditions of the form $y(x_0) = y_0$ the solution will only be defined for $x>1$ if $x_0>1$, and $x<0$ for $x_0<1$, since the solution has a pole at $x=1$. Again, this assumes that $y_0\neq \pm 2x_0$, which would again provide a global solution.

Separation of variables, or whatever method you use to find the general solution of the ODE, does indeed not extend to $x=1$. But this is a limitation of the method, not of the solutions. As we have seen, the particular solution you are interested in extends to all of $\mathbb R$.

**Comment.** Solving the ODE becomes even easier when introducing $u(x) = z(x)(x-1)$, since then we need to solve $u'= 4x(3x-2)$. However, this does not make it easier to deal with the singularity at $x=1$.