# Solve the differential equation $2xyy′ + 1 + y^2 = 0. $ and also find the maximal interval of the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $2xyy′ + 1 + y^2 = 0. $  and also find
> the maximal interval of the solution.

Still I don't understand this concept of finding maximal interval of the solution.

Consider the differential equation $2xyy′ + 1 + y^2 = 0. $ Find the maximal interval of the solution.

My attempt:

I got the general solution as $(y(x))^2=\frac{c}{x}-1$.

How do I find the maximal interval of the solution?

I followed the steps in the answer given in the question.
[Solve the differential equation $y'+4xy=4x\sqrt{y}$ and also find the maximal interval of the solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814895/solve-the-differential-equation-y4xy-4x-sqrty-and-also-find-the-maximal-in)

and
[Solve the differential equation $y'-2y=e^{2x}. $ Find the maximal interval of the solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815228/solve-the-differential-equation-y-2y-e2x-find-the-maximal-interval-of-th)

When $c=0$. It is clear that $y(x)$ does not defined in $\mathbb R$
When $c>0$, $\frac{c}{x}>1\implies \frac{x}{c}<1 \implies 0<x<c.$
When $c<0$, $\frac{c}{x}>1\implies \frac{x}{c}<1 \implies 0>x>c(\because c<0).$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are. ${}$